# What are my options to generate vacuum for impregnating with resin/epoxy?

Tags: epoxy

I have some small parts (wood, or even FR4 plates like for PCBs) which I want to seal against humidity. My idea is to slightly impregnate them with epoxy.

To avoid bubbles under the coat and to enhance penetration in the wood fibres or in the FR4 voids I would like to vacuum the part so that resin will penetrate a little more when vacuum is removed.

What are my options to achieve vacuum?

I am aware of using a vacuum cleaner, but is the vacuum strong enough? also, does vacuum need to be maintained for several minutes for this purpose, or are a couple of minutes enough? a vacuum cleaner motor without the flow of air will overheat extremely quickly.

What other cheap options are available for casual use?

Comment: If you're just seeking to seal wood against humidity you don't need anything more than extremely shallow penetration and you'll get some just soaking the parts in the liquid resin (same as you do if you soak parts in finishes like varnish or lacquer). I imagine if you can rig something up using a vacuum cleaner it could provide some extra oomph, but it may not actually be needed and it would save having to get over the technical hurdles. So first thing I suggest you do is try it sans vacuum, see how you get on.

Comment: Who's downvoting without commenting about the reasons??

Comment: Why do you think that's a requirement? https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Graphus I understood from other communities that it was suggested to explain the reasons. No rule broken, as you point out, just not very helpful.

Comment: There's a lot of difference on opinion on that point across SE. Some see downvotes as in some way harmful, when they're just the flipside of upvotes which together are necessary for weighting/grading (same as they were on YouTube before a few weeks ago, when thumbsdowns were inexplicably hidden from public view). Anyway, one of the best pros-and-cons thing I've ever seen on this is from the meta of another Stack, [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/how-to-guarantee-getting-downvotes-without-explanation) if you want to read it.

Comment: I downvoted because "This question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, you don't really have to do this to protect wood from humidity. Depending on the application, some wood is used without any finish at all because that has proven the most effective.

However, if you want to experiment a shop vacuum and some of those cheap vacuum storage bags will probably be fine, especially for your first experiments.

But the real answer here is if you want to finish wood to protect it against moisture, use a penetrating finish of any kind and just brush or spray it on.

Comment: +1, but, your closing line is actually way off the mark. Vacuum or pressure impregnation using resins of various kinds is an existing shop-level thing — many amateurs mess about with it for producing pen blanks, strengthening and colouring punky wood for knife scales and other things on that sort of small scale.

Comment: Fair enough, though I have to admit I never see the usual suspects talking about. I had the impression vacuum system were more for getting bubble-free veneers and so on. I'll change it.

Comment: The vacuum (or pressure, they can be kinda similar) systems for the sort of thing I mention are very different to what's used in veneering. Think more compressor pump + pressure cooker than large, flat vacuum bag.

Comment: Uh, link is worth a thousand words and all that: https://www.tdpri.com/threads/experiments-with-vacuum-infusion-and-cactus-juice.626505/

Comment: Oh, maybe I recall seeing one of those devices used on a "pour epoxy into a mould full of stuff and then turn it on the lathe" YouTube site.

Comment: That makes sense since they'll want to degass the resin to prevent trapped bubbles. I wouldn't know for sure since I make it an absolute point to avoid those "pour epoxy into a mould full of stuff and then turn it on the lathe" YouTube videos LOL

Comment: You and me both. I respect the skill, but at this point it's a bit of a played out trope.